# Analytic solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

In a book about differential equantions I have read that if the function $f$ in analytic, then a solution of $y'=f(x,y)$ is analytic. Is there a good book that prove this claim?

Comment: Gerald Teschl's ODE and Dynamical systems. On the author's webpage you can find legal free copy.